# Как задать одному объекту скорость и направление другого в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть два объекта в сцене. Один из них я "запускаю" с помощью SpringJoint2D. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы другой объект полетел с такой же скоростью в таком же направлении как и этот?